# AlertDialog not disappearing when alert.Dispose() is called(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I declare AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertConfirmTransfer = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertConfirmTransfer.SetMessage("Some message");
alertConfirmTransfer.SetPositiveButton("YES", delegate
{
    alertConfirmTransfer.Dispose();
});
alertConfirmTransfer.SetNegativeButton("NO", delegate
{
    alertConfirmTransfer.Dispose();
});

Dialog dialogConfirmTransfer = alertConfirmTransfer.Create();
dialogConfirmTransfer.Show();
```

When the dialog appears and I click yes or no the dialog disappears but if in the SetPositiveButton I put a try-catch block under

```
alertConfirmTransfer.Dispose();
```

nad the try'catch slows down when I click Yes button, the dialog stays on screen

Comment: Why did you add `alertConfirmTransfer.Dispose()`? There is no need to do this, when you click the button or outside of the dialog, it will disappear automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to dismiss the dialog by using the [Cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel()) method.

Declare the local variable Dialog `dialogConfirmTransfer` above the AlertDialog.Builder. Initialize it the same way as you do now. And call `dialogConfirmTranser.Cancel()` in the delegates for your buttons.